# About write permission for directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why can't I create a file even when the directory has write permissions for other?

For example

- I create a directory as root

  mkdir qq-201505221157

  The file is

  drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root        4096 May 22 11:57 qq-201505221157
- I change permissions like this to set only white permissions fot others

  chmod 002 qq-201505221157

  The file now is

  d-------w-  2 root          root        4096 May 22 11:57 qq-201505221157
- I try to create a file with another user (elamas)

  touch qq-201505221157/elamas.txt

The result is

touch: cannot touch âqq-201505221157/elamas.txtâ: Permission denied

Why is it?

Thanks

Comment: You get permission denied as you are not allowed to switch to or enter the directory

Answer (score 0):

you dont have permission to read the folder. yes, you can write to it or remove it as any user but not see it!

```
chmod 002 #means: world has permission to write it.
chmod 004 #means: world has permission to read it.
chmod 001 #means: world has permission to execute it.
```

for being able to read/write you can simply add these numbers together

```
chmod 007 #means world can read/write/execute.
```

run:

```
man chmod
```

for more info